# Дать значение html-элементу

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Как дать значение через simple html dom мета тэгу description? А если тэга нет, предварительно создать его.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам:

```
if(($html->find('meta[name="keywords"]', 0))) {
                $htmlmod->find("meta[name='keywords']", 0)->content = $value;
            }else{
                $html->find('head', 0)->innertext .= '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$value.'">';
            }
```